# Springboot and Thymeleaf very long url's

Tags: spring, url, thymeleaf

While working on my project I encountered an issue with the URL.
I have around 10 entities and all working with the primary key in the URL to do things like update, create and read.

Example url:

```
"/project/projectID/clust/clustID/tr/trID/story/storyID/design/designID...."
```

The more objects there are, the longer my URL gets. 
When i'm at design I only need the ID of story to create/update the design and not all the previous ID's and URL part. 
The only reason I keep extending my URL is to have navigability for the user to go from design to project for example.

Each method in my controller has a lot of @Pathvariables for all the ID's and I keep giving all the ID's to the model.addAttribute to the view. The reason for this is to build the URL in a button on the view when a user wants to navigate to somewhere else.

Long story short:

My URL keeps getting longer and longer, the only reason for this is to navigate.
Controller methods have a long parameter list of @Pathvariables and a lot of model.attributes to put all the ID's in the Thymeleaf view.
I'm using thymeleaf with Spring Boot.
All my entities are bidirectional. So If you have a design, it is possible to retrieve the project.

How can I resolve this 'problem' and still keep the navigability?

Comment: Are you talking about REST architecture?

Comment: You can avoid it by not storing the id's in the path, but providing them directly in the model.